# $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'] is empty on select .mp4 and .pdf files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, file-upload

am trying to upload files and I discovered that ['tmp_name'] is empty if I select .mp4 file, .pdf and even flv. it works fine with image and doc files and other..
my html

```
<form id="MaterialUpload" action="#" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-      data' class="form-horizontal form-row-seperated">
                                                                 <input     type="file" name="fileUpload" class="form-control" />


// javascript posting it via ajax
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '../CONTROLLER/MaterialAPI.php?CreateCategory=true=',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formData,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
                $(".auctncr").html(data);
        },

// php 
echo $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: am on php 7 brothers

Comment: maybe max file size exceeded?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: yea, that works now. thanks a lot. by why is the idiot not throwing error for max file size exceeding....?

Comment: not even a NOTICE/Warning? got error_reporting on strictest level?

Comment: All error conditions are given here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php Except if `$_FILES` is empty, the `post_max_size` hits and you don't get an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini change upload_max_filesize.

upload_max_filesize = 2M replace 2 with 6 or 10

Comment: since your answer is a guess you should also include the other possibilities.  like post_max_size, ..